# ASP If Statement if Split() is empty as I get Subscript out of range: '[number: 1]'

Tags: asp-classic, outofrangeexception

I have a single form field that asks for "Full Name" when the user signs up.  I want to then split that string into first name and then surname.  I can get that working with the following code:

```
<%
If Request.Form("user[username]") <> "" Then
     NameStr = Request.Form("user[username]")
     Dim WordArray
     WordArray = Split(NameStr, " ")
End If
%>
```

From that I can then split the variables into my form with:

```
value="<%=WordArray(0)%>"
value="<%=WordArray(1)%>"
```

However, if the user just puts their first name in I get an error as the Split is looking for a space between the words to perform the action correctly.  I have tried:

```
<%
If Request.Form("user[username]") <> "" Then
    NameStr = Request.Form("user[username]")
    Dim WordArray
            If NameStr = "" Then
                    WordArray = Split(NameStr, "")
            Else
                    WordArray = Split(NameStr, " ")
            End If
End If
%>
```

Now I knew this would fail as it will never be blank but is there a way to look to see if the Split will error if there is only a first name and no surname?  I have looked at validating the form field but cannot see a way of ensuring it has a space between them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`Split` is not the problem. If the string doesn't have a space in it, `Split` won't throw an error, but will return an array with only one element. What you should do  is check the upper bound of `WordArray` using the `UBound` function:

```
Dim WordArray, firstName, lastName
WordArray = Split(NameStr, " ")

firstName = WordArray(0)
If UBound(WordArray) >= 1 Then
    lastName = WordArray(1)
Else
    lastName = ""
End If
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I managed to get it working as per my own answer yesterday however I think your solution is a better one.

Answer (score -1):

It's not really a fix, but I managed some "old school" VBA techniques and it has at least trapped the error:

```
<%
If Request.Form("user[username]") <> "" Then
    NameStr = Request.Form("user[username]")
    Dim WordArray
        WordArray = Split(NameStr, " ")
        On Error Resume Next
End If
%>
```

The `On Error Resume Next` just ignores the error and moves on.  Dirty (just like ASP is, but it works!).